# Doesn't create a migration in tests(I'm using rspec), but in development it works

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my console:

```
ilya@SamsungRV-509:~/MyProjects/easy_learning$ rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
==  SetPasswordToAdministrator: migrating =====================================
DEPRECATION WARNING: This dynamic method is deprecated. Please use e.g. Post.find_or_create_by(name: 'foo') instead. (called from up at /home/ilya/MyProjects/easy_learning/db/migrate/20131210185519_set_password_to_administrator.rb:3)
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `mobile' for #<User:0xba972894>/home/ilya/MyProjects/easy_learning/db/migrate/20131210185519_set_password_to_administrator.rb:3:in `up'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my file:

```
class SetPasswordToAdministrator < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    admin = ::User.find_or_create_by_email_and_name("admin@email.com", "Admin")
    admin.password = admin.password_confirmation = "easylearning"
    admin.role = "Administrator"
    admin.save!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run two rake tasks (or ensure they've been run) first to get going with Rspec as it relates to your DB:

```
rake db:create:all
```

This ensures that your test DB was created.

```
rake db:migrate db:test:clone
```

This will ensure that your test database is both up-to-date and ready for your specs to run.

Over the last year as I've worked to get better about T/BDD and Rspec in particular, I no longer even run `rake db:migrate` alone. I always run `rake db:migrate db:test:clone` now!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Rails 4.1+, RSpec has a feature that keeps your test database synchronised with development. This from the RSpec website:

> To take advantage of this add the following to the top of the rails_helper file after Rails has been required:
>
> `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!`

Behaviour in Rails 4.0 is slightly different. Here is the page for more information:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#pending-migration-checks